# Custom dimensions for iphone 5 (320px width) vs iphone 6 (375px width)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, autolayout

I'm new to IOS and I noticed that IOS has size classes (compact vs regular). Unfortunately, I also noticed that the older iphone models (4,5) that have logical pixels of 320px vs the newer models 375px are classified under the same size class.

This is rather unfortunate as I was hoping to tailor my layout to take advantage of those extra 40px.

Is it possible to do this in any other way or do I just have to manually check it when the view gets loaded and change them programatically.

Comment: Without seeing the layout that you have planned, we can't give you any specific advice. In general, it is best to avoid checking the screen's actual pixel sizes and to have your layouts for all the different phones look similar and scale appropriately to the size. `UIStackView` can be used to create some custom layouts that adapt to the given size. What are you looking to use that 40 pixels for that can't be done on smaller phones?

Comment: @keithbhunter The main reason is I am porting an app from Android. And the android app has a `sw-360dp` section in its values.